# Capture error message from Sp_send_dbmail to catch block

Tags: sql-server-2019

I have a below query in the stored procedure. And I have the invalid location `@file_attachments`.

```
BEGIN TRY

EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail 
    @recipients='raja@gmail.com', 
    @subject='hello', 
    @body='hello', 
    @body_format='HTML', 
    @file_attachments='\\1.1.1.1\Image\Logo.png', 
    @profile_name='EmailDev'

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, 
          ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage    
END CATCH
```

When I execute I'm getting this error:

> Msg 22051, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
> Attachment file \1.1.1.1\Image\Logo.png is invalid.

But I'm not able to capture this in error in the catch block, rather it is not hitting the catch block.

How to capture the error message in the catch block instead of the standard way of displaying an error?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a problem sp_send_dbmail to capture the error in TRY CATCH block.

As per the suggestion on the [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2214f911-bfea-40f2-94f5-0a709686a401/try-catch-problem?forum=transactsql)

I have modified my code as below, which solves my problem.

```
BEGIN TRY

Declare @FileInfo Table(FileExist Int,IsDirectory Int,ParentDirectoryExist Int)
Declare @file_attachments VARCHAR(1000)
SET @file_attachments = '\\1.1.1.1\Image\Logo.png'

INSERT INTO @AtthacmentFileInfo EXEC XP_FILEEXIST @Attachment
IF (SELECT FileExist FROM @AtthacmentFileInfo)=0
BEGIN
    SET @ErrMessage = 'Invalid logo location or it is not accessible. '+@Attachment+''
    ;THROW 50000,@ErrMessage,1;
END
                
EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail 
        @recipients='raja@gmail.com', 
        @subject='hello', 
        @body='hello', 
        @body_format='HTML', 
        @file_attachments='\\1.1.1.1\Image\Logo.png', 
        @profile_name='echohealth'

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, 
       ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage    
END CATCH
```

Comment: This error (raised by a system external stored procedure) can't be caught with T-SQL structured error handling. There may be others so I suggest you catch the error in the app code that calls the proc.